# Gradle compile QuerydslJava failed

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, gradle, querydsl

I'm using gradle, springBoot, querydsl and mongodb.
Added next gradle settings follow [this article](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/003_tip_add_querydsl_support.html):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.9"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "$buildDir/generated/source/app/main"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.4"
    compileOnly "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4"
}

querydsl {
    springDataMongo = true
    querydslSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/source/app/main"
}
```

It works fine when I start project using `gradle bootRun`, but when I'm just using `gradle clean build` it fails when compiling querydsl.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileQuerydslJava'.
> Compilation failed with exit code 1; see the compiler error output for details.

/Volumes/DATA/notification-service/app/build/generated/source/app/main/net/platform/notification/domain/impl/entity/QNotification.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    public QNotification(Path<? extends Notification> path) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class Path
  location: class QNotification
/Volumes/DATA/notification-service/app/build/generated/source/app/main/net/platform/notification/domain/impl/entity/QNotification.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    public QNotification(Path<? extends Notification> path) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Notification
  location: class QNotification
/Volumes/DATA/notification-service/app/build/generated/source/app/main/net/platform/notification/domain/impl/entity/QNotification.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
    public QNotification(PathMetadata metadata) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class PathMetadata
  location: class QNotification
/Volumes/DATA/notification-service/app/build/generated/source/app/main/net/platform/notification/domain/impl/entity/QNotification.java:5: error: package com.querydsl.core.types.dsl does not exist
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;
^
```

Why it fails during build and works fine after bootRun ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in pmd plugin.

I've excluded `compileQuerydslJava` task from my build `./gradlew clean build -x compileQuerydslJava` and got next error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:pmdQuerydsl'.
> 46 PMD rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///Volumes/DATA/notification-service/app/build/reports/pmd/querydsl.html
```

So I specified source set for pmd plugin

```
pmd {
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    }
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: I have a similar problem and tried your approach. Although the build passed the QClasses were not generated - which makes sense. After all `-x compileQuerydslJava` skips the process which generates them. The QClasses were generated for you?

Comment: In my case I had another issue before task compileQueryDsl, I've excluded this task and figured out what the error (it was pmd).
In your case, what error do you see when execute `build` task?

Comment: When I add the ewerk plugin the `build` task can't find `JpaAnnotationProcessor` and several other dependencies. If I remove the plugin the `build` is successful, but the QClasses are not generated. By adding the plugin and using your approach of `./gradlew clean build -x compileQuerydslJava` the `build` passes, but the QClasses are not generated.
In the end I removed the plugin and created the QClasses by hand. That solved my problem.

Comment: It's not the best solution.
Actually, there are a lot of questions. I think you should create a separate question.
Because for example in new gradle > 5.0 you should apply query dsl plugin in a little bit different way.
Something like:
`apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt'
}

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}`

Comment: @ernani, pls take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913274/querydsl-annotation-processor-issue-after-upgrade-to-gradle-5