# Querydsl Annotation Processor issue after upgrade to Gradle 5

Tags: java, gradle, querydsl

I have a gradle script which generates querydsl classes from Mongo annotated entities. It was working so far, but after upgrade to Gradle 5 I have a problem with:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myproject-common:compileQuerydsl'.
Annotation processor 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor' not found
```

Please find my gradle.build script below. Any ideas what could be wrong? I read that there was change in Gradle 5 that annotation processors are not used by default during compilation and annotationProcessor declaration should be added but when I add it to dependencies the same error occurs.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
jar {
    enabled = true
    baseName = 'myproject-common'
    version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
// do no package commons into fat jar
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
querydsl {
    library = 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4'
    querydslSourcesDir = 'src/main/querydsl'
    springDataMongo = true
}
sourceCompatibility = 11.0
targetCompatibility = 11.0
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/querydsl']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-    jsr310:2.8.6")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:23.0")
    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.5")
    compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5")
    compile("commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2")
    compile("org.javamoney:moneta:1.1")
    compile("com.fizzed:rocker-runtime:1.2.0")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.1.4")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.4")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4")
    compile("com.codepoetics:protonpack:1.15")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.7.0")
}
```

Comment: Michal, did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: just a workaround described below in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is my working configuration for JPA without using additional plugins. Gradle 5.3, openjdk 11.0.2.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.2.0.M1'
    queryDslVersion = '4.2.1'
}

dependencies {
    api(
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:$queryDslVersion"
    )

    implementation(
            platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion"),
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            'org.liquibase:liquibase-core',
            'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    )

    annotationProcessor(
            platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion"),
            'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api',
            'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api',
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$queryDslVersion:jpa"

    )
}
```

Please pay attention to the annotation processor. It has suffix ":jpa". Probably this is what you missed. To activate the same one for mongodb you should add ":morphia" suffix.

Please also look at these 2 dependencies:

```
'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api'
'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api'
```

This is a workaround for the issue described here:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/annotationprocessor-querydsl-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/27107
They should be transitive dependencies of the annotation processor, but they aren't yet. Probably you will have to include some mongo dependencies to annotationProcessor too.
Generated sources are located in `\build\generated\sources\annotationProcessor\java\main`

Comment: Great first answer @niebaraka. FWIW a more conventional transitive dependency for the :jpa processor would be     `annotationProcessor("javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api")`

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia I don't carefully follow the latest changes in EE world, but seems `jakarta.*` is now a preferable option over `javax.*` At least spring boot 2.0.0.M1 already includes mentioned dependencies, that's why I used them too.

Comment: agreed, though Spring Boot [2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.0.M1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) will use them, the current 2.1.4 GA dependencies BOM doesn't mention them

Answer (score 7):

I have finally found a workaround. Querydsl's lack of compatibility with Gradle 5 is reported here as a bug: https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/issues/108

Workaround is to add to gradle script:

```
compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

Comment: where exactly do we need to add this block? I got this exception after adding it : `org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method compileQuerydsl() for arguments [build_34f65uphys3x3neud0s7h85bz$_run_closure1$_closure14@47966d1f] on root project 'my-project' of type org.gradle.api.Project`

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by adding the following two dependencies.

```
annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa"
annotationProcessor 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.1'
```

The second dependency was a hidden reason why it not worked for me.

Comment: What's your gradle version?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue for Spring Boot Data JPA and Query DSL with Gradle 6.6.1. I tried so many things in my `build.gradle` file, including some of the suggestions in other responses to this question. I was able to come up with a `build.gradle` file with a minimal set of additions to the standard build file (standard in the sense of the one generated by https://start.spring.io). Here it is:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl' version "1.0.10"
}

group = 'org.code'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

querydsl {
    querydslDefault = true
    jpa = true
}

configurations {
    querydsl.extendsFrom implementation
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}

ext {
    queryDslVersion = '4.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The key addition is the Query DSL plugin:

```
id 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl' version "1.0.10"
```

However, it is not enough on its own. Other important additions are:

```
querydsl {
    querydslDefault = true
    jpa = true
}

configurations {
    querydsl.extendsFrom implementation
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration i am using,it works:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"

}

group = 'io.loremipsum'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


querydsl {
    library = 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4'
    querydslSourcesDir = 'src/main/querydsl'
    springDataMongo = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/querydsl']
        }
    }
}
// is required when gradle > 5.0
compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.1.4")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.4")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4")

    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo'
}
```

pay attention to the dependency declaration：

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
```

implementation dependency should not be used or will result in an exception:

```
Annotation processor 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor' not found
```

Comment: I did not understand your comment "pay attention to the dependency declaration". Are we suppose to remove the spring mongo dependency?

Answer (score -1):

I see you have `compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4")` in your dependencies. According to [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_compile_avoidance)

> Since implementation details matter for annotation processors, they must be declared separately on the annotation processor path. **Gradle ignores annotation processors on the compile classpath.**

So, put `com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4` in the `annotationProcessor` scope.

BTW, consider switching to [`api` / `implementation`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) scopes over `compile`.

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer, I have added two lines


    `annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4"
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb"`
but it did not help and error is the same. Do you have any other ideas?