# Java 11 + QueryDSL 4 + Gradle 5 + SpringBoot 2.1- not generating QClasses

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, querydsl, lombok

I’m trying to integrate **QueryDSL, Gradle and Springboot** in versions from title.
I added annotationProcessors to gradle but Intellij is still not generating the QClasses. I tried sugesstions from community to use the plugin ‘gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin’
but this did not help.

```
dependencies{
   annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4")
   annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1")
   annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE")

   compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4")
   implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1")
   implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE")
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE")
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your configuration. Because in my case it puts the generated files in the build/class/java/main/ folder.

Answer (score 8):

You need to provide concrete annotation processor **':jpa'**

```
annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")
```

that should work:

```
dependencies{
   annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4")
   annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa")
   annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE")

   compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4")
   implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1")
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE")
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE")
}
```

Comment: annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa") is not working for me. Gradle message Annotation processor 'com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor' not found. Anything i a missing? Using gradle 5.4 and jdk 8

Comment: @TosKen checkout my answer, I had the same trouble

Answer (score 8):

I will give you my working configuration :

```
ext {
    queryDslVersion = '4.2.1'
    lombokVersion = '1.8.6'
}
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441844/annotation-processor-in-intellij-and-gradle/54611475#54611475
compileJava {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
}

dependencies {
  // ...

    compile(
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    )

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa",
            "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final",
            "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2",
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
}
```

**Using Gradle 5.2+**

Comment: This works for me in Gradle 5.6 with only `annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.2:jpa",           "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final"`.

Comment: @TecHunter this doesn't work for me with `Gradle 5.1`. I am still getting the same error as OP, i.e. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotation processor 'com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor' not found`

Comment: @DarshanMehta try gradle 5.2+ unless you are restricted with versions

Comment: @TecHunter unfortunately I have to stick to `5.1` due to restrictions

Comment: @DarshanMehta post another SO question with this specificity and reference this post. can't help you sorry

Comment: @TecHunter here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320937/gradle-unable-to-generate-querydsl-classes

Comment: this answer worked with Gradle 5.6.4, but not on gradle 6.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the exact same order

```
sourceSets {
  generated {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main']
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
    api 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor('com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.4.0:jpa')
    annotationProcessor('javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **This works in intellij!!**

```
    ext {
            queryDslVersion = '4.2.1'
            
        }
        
       idea {
          module {
        sourceDirs += file('generated/')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('generated/')
    }
} 
        
        
         dependencies {
                compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")
                compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}")
            }
            
            dependencies {
            
                compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
                compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
                annotationProcessor(
                    "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa",
                    "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final",
                    "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2",
                    "org.projectlombok:lombok"
                )

}
```

Answer (score -1):

QueryDSL doesn't work with Gradle 5. You can check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913274/querydsl-annotation-processor-issue-after-upgrade-to-gradle-5) and the [plug-in issues](https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/issues/108) for more information.

It looks like some people managed to get it to work with workarounds such as the ones in the linked question, but that has not been my case. My team had to resort to using HQL in the end.

Comment: It works well (I'm using it with 5.3 right now).
`compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}`
Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913274/querydsl-annotation-processor-issue-after-upgrade-to-gradle-5#answer-53930957

Comment: @Max this isn't working for me, unfortunately... I either have to use HQL or add QueryDSL without the Gradle plugin and create the QClasse manually. What are the configurations of your project? Java version, Spring version... are they the same ones as the question title?